# Array in C containing Incorrect Values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The goal of this program is to add the first and last elements of an array together and set that value as the first element of an output array, and then continue moving inwards as such. All of the sums will be stored in an output array. For this program, the rules stipulate that I may only use pointers and pointer arithmetic (i.e. no subscripting, no '[]', etc.) I have gotten the program to work for arrays of length 2 as well and length 4 (as I have only implemented functionality for even-lengthed arrays) however when I try any array of length 6 or above, the program adds together incorrect values that are not in the first array.

I have already tried using two different debuggers to isolate where the problem is coming from and for the life of me I can not figure it out. I have spent a few hours looking over my notes on C and going through the code, reworking it however I can. I feel as if there is something wrong with how I am interacting between the array and the pointer variables, but I am unsure. I couldn't seem to find any questions on Stack Overflow too similar to this one (yes, I looked).

```
void add(int *a1, int array_size, int *a2) {

    int * p;
    int * temp = (a1+(array_size-1));

    if (array_size % 2 == 0) {
        array_size = array_size/2;
        for (p = a2; p < (a2+array_size); p++) {
            *p = *a1 + *temp;
            printf("%d", *a1);
            printf(" + %d", *temp);
            a1++;
            temp--;
            printf(" = %d\n", *p);
        }
    }

}
```

For arrays of length 2 and 4 (again, I am only testing even numbers for now), the code works fine.

**Example Output:**

```
Enter the length of the array: 2                                                                                               

Enter the elements of the array:  1 2                                                                                          
1 + 2 = 3   
The output array is: 3

Enter the length of the array: 4                                                                                               

Enter the elements of the array:  1 2 3 4                                                                                      
1 + 4 = 5                                                                                                                      
2 + 3 = 5  
The output array is: 5 5
```

***Now this is where it is going wrong.***

When I do this:

```
Enter the length of the array: 6                                                                                                 

Enter the elements of the array:  1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I expect:

```
1 + 6 = 7                                                                                                                        
2 + 5 = 7                                                                                                                        
3 + 4 = 7 

The output array is: 7 7 7
```

But *instead*, the output is:

```
1 + 0 = 1                                                                                                                        
2 + 3 = 5                                                                                                                        
3 + 4 = 7          

The output array is: 1 5 7
```

My best guess is that something went wrong with my use of pointers or perhaps pointer syntax. Any help I can get, positive or negative, would be greatly appreciated.

This is the main() function:

```
int main() {

  int size = 0;
  int out_size = 0;
  int arr[size];

  printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", & size);
  printf("\nEnter the elements of the array:  ");
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf("%d", & arr[i]);
  }

  if (size % 2 == 0) {
      out_size = size/2;
  }
  else{
      out_size = ((size-1)/2) + 1;
  }

  int out[out_size];

  //calling the add function and using the addresses of arrays + array size
  add(arr, size, out);

  //iterating through and printing output array which has now been
  //altered by the move function
  printf("\nThe output array is: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < out_size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", out[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you making sure the `a2` array is sufficiently large?

Comment: yes a2 is based on the sums of the digits from a1 therefore it is half the size

Comment: also, while I don't find this problem particularly interesting, here's a +1 from me for a well-written post!

Comment: thank you bolov I appreciate that

Comment: well-written to me implicates a self-contained MCVE, which this question unfortunately lacks, although it would have been no problem.

Comment: I suspect your problem may be in the way you process input from the user (`Enter the elements of the array:  1 2 3 4 5 6` ).

Comment: that is all done in the main function. If it would provide more clarity into how the elements are added to the array, I could post that as well?

Comment: @MatthewThibodeau Yes, there are potential issues there.

Comment: @JosuGoñi the main function has been added

Comment: Your output array `arr` has zero size. You had to declare it _after_ the first scanf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an array of size 0:

```
int main() {
    int size = 0;
    int out_size = 0;
    int arr[size]; // <- Here is your problem
```

You could move the array declarations after the `size` reading:

```
int main() {
    int size = 0;
    int out_size = 0;

    printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", & size);
    int arr[size];

    printf("\nEnter the elements of the array:  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", & arr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: A suggested fix would greatly improve your answer

Comment: I read through it and I am unsure how I missed such a minuscule little error but it all seems clear to me now. Feel free to take down this question moderators. I've had enough public humiliation for one day. Thank you both

Comment: @MatthewThibodeau It happens from time to time to everyone ;)

Comment: I couldn't believe my eyes when I saw that about two hours of me checking all my pointers and variables boiled down to a simple error in the first few lines. How silly of me. Thanks again for catching that!

Comment: @MatthewThibodeau the best you can learn from this is to always post an MCVE in the first place, makes life easier for everyone.